# Pycparser parse error on byteswap.h

Tags: python, centos7, pycparser

I know that this is a pretty specific issue but I've done about all I can to search for an answer and still haven't come up with anything of value. I'm using pycparser to try and parse some code in (surprise, surprise) and when it does the linking it fails with the error below. If anyone has any thoughts, I'd be grateful for some help.

```
  File "test.py", line 14, in <module>
    cpp_args=['-E', r'-Iutils/fake_libc_include'])
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pycparser/__init__.py", line 93, in parse_file
    return parser.parse(text, filename)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pycparser/c_parser.py", line 146, in parse
    debug=debuglevel)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ply/yacc.py", line 265, in parse
    return self.parseopt_notrack(input,lexer,debug,tracking,tokenfunc)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ply/yacc.py", line 1047, in parseopt_notrack
    tok = self.errorfunc(errtoken)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pycparser/c_parser.py", line 1680, in p_error
    column=self.clex.find_tok_column(p)))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pycparser/plyparser.py", line 55, in
_parse_error
    raise ParseError("%s: %s" % (coord, msg))

/usr/include/bits/byteswap.h:46:1: before: {
```

This is on CentOS 7.

The code:

```
      (((x) & 0x0000ff00) <<  8) | (((x) & 0x000000ff) << 24))

#ifdef __GNUC__
# if __GNUC_PREREQ (4, 3)
static __inline unsigned int
__bswap_32 (unsigned int __bsx)
{
  return __builtin_bswap32 (__bsx);
}
# elif __GNUC__ >= 2
#  if __WORDSIZE == 64 || (defined __i486__ || defined __pentium__            \
                           || defined __pentiumpro__ || defined __pentium4__  \
                           || defined __k8__ || defined __athlon__            \
                           || defined __k6__ || defined __nocona__            \
                           || defined __core2__ || defined __geode__          \
                           || defined __amdfam10__)
```

Comment: please provide the code of `byte swap.h` from line 40 to 50

Comment: Added it, sorry about that!

Comment: Is this _the only_ error message you're getting? It's pretty meaningless, to my mind, it should be longer

Comment: It also shows the stacktrace, which I've appended to the original question.

Comment: Well, line 40 looks weird, it should end with a semicolon, to my mind

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I don't *really* have an answer but I'll at least post this as a workaround in case anyone else is having the same issue.  I have to manually run my code through a preprocessor as I think there are some compiler issues that give pycparser issues (its weird, I know).  Anyway, preprocessing the code manually then parsing using pycparser worked for me!

Answer (score 1):

pyparser doesn't support compiler specific keywords like `__inline`. You have to use the fake_libc_include headers. See https://github.com/eliben/pycparser/wiki/FAQ